# Using d3.js svg library works freeze on smart phones

Tags: html, web-applications, d3.js

I am developing a web page that uses d3.js library for a animated undirected graph visual, but I discovered that (after lots of work done) it works so freezing on mobile.

Do you know any solution for such problem, or do I need to change my way of creating the visual? For example is using html5 canvas more elegant solution for the problem?

Thanks for the answers folks :)